# Remove object from array if object parameter value already exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble finding the most optimal solution to except using a double for loop for my situation.

Assuming I have an array objects:

```
let array = [{param1:"A", param2:"B"}, {param1:"C", param2:"D"},{param1:"A", param2:"E"}]
```

How can I remove the duplicates based on `param1` value except using two forloops?

So far I detect duplicates using:

```
const param1Values = new Set(array.map(item => item.param1));
const hasDuplicates = paramValues.size != array.length;
```

How can I clean `array` so I only have:

```
[{param1:"A", param2:"B"}, {param1:"C", param2:"D"}]
```

**EDIT**

We want to keep the first instance of `param1` and remove the rest

Comment: Why is the object with `B` chosen and not the object with `E`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, it looks like the rule: *keeping the first of the same group*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array with a closure over the set.

```js
const
    array = [{ param1: "A", param2: "B" }, { param1: "C", param2: "D" }, { param1: "A", param2: "E" }],
    result = array.filter(
        (seen => ({ param1 }) => !seen.has(param1) && seen.add(param1))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm passin an array of keys to compare but you can simplify it by passing a unique key

```js
function uniq(array, uniqProperties) {
    return array.filter(
        (value, index, self) =>
            index === self.findIndex(
                t => uniqProperties.every(property => t[property] === value[property])
            )
  )
}

const response = uniq([{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}, {"key": "value2"}], ["key"])
console.log(response) 

/* Response:
  [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value2"}]
*/
```